# Conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: magento2, ssh, third-party-plugin

i want try doofinder in my magento 2.2.6 ecommerce but when i try to install it i get this error:

```
Using version ^0.1.7@beta for doofinder/doofinder-magento2
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
packages.
Problem 1
- The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 
2.1.0, required as 2.2.6) is satisfiable by magento/product-community- 
edition[2.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.6, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.6, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 101.0.6].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires magento/framework 
101.0.6 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> 
satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
- Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.0) -> 
satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0].
```

Answer (score 3):

add this `--ignore-platform-reqs` option on your composer install command,

it should be :

`composer install doofinder/doofinder-magento2 --ignore-platform-reqs`

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again