# Facing issues on upgrade magento in magento cloud, upgrade magento to latest version of magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.2

Right now we are working on updating magento to latest version of magento 2.3.2 right now we are runing 2.2.7.

I following the guide for 2.3 branch found at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

I have taken following steps :

Step1: Update ece-tools version

On local workstation, perform an update using Composer

> composer update magento/ece-tools

Add, commit, and push code changes.

> git add -A && git commit -m “Update magento/ece-tools” && git push origin

Step2: Back up the database

Create a local backup of the remote database.

> magento-cloud db:dump

when i run this command in my terminal i get ‘magento-cloud’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Back up code and media.

> php bin/magento setup:backup –code [–media]

To back up Staging or Production environment database before deploying

> php vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump

Step3: Complete the upgrade

I have PHP 7.1.30 version

Before completing the upgrade, update the autoload property I follow all the steps giving in 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#update-autoload

set the upgrade version using

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 –no-update

Then Update the project

> composer update

After composer update i get some error

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

- Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.2.7 <2.2.8 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.2.7].
```

Can you please guide me how can i solve this issue..

Thanks in advance.

My composer.json is

```
{
"name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.3.2",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"repositories": {
    "repo": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
    },
    "amasty": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/enterprise/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": ">=2.2.7 <2.2.8",
    "gene/bluefoot": "^1.0",
    "amasty/promo": "^2.2",
    "sashas/bug-from-email": "^2.0",
    "amasty/shopby": "^2.11",
    "amasty/label": "^1.10",
    "connectpos/rest-api": "^1.1",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
    "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.2"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "magento-force": true,
    "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~1.0.0",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.14",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
}}
```

Comment: What if you run composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition, it looks like you missing this package. And check do you have access for this user to magento-cloud

Comment: Thanks @BartZalas 
I run "composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition" then i get some new errors in my terminal like
`Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.2.7, required as 2.3.2) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`

Comment: other errors is 
`Problem 2
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.7 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

    - Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.2.7 <2.2.8 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.2.7].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.`

Comment: With that please read composer docs first. You can remove package and install needed  version. or remove composer.lock and run composer install. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247536/conflict-with-your-requirements-or-minimum-stability

Comment: Thank you @BartZalas i remove composer.lock from root directory and run composer install then i face same error that i mention in my question above..

Comment: So You need change versions of this magento/product-community-edition. composer remove magento/product-community-edition and later composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.3.2 and finally composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition

Comment: Okay @BartZalas I follow all the instruction giving by you but unfortunately i'm getting same error as above..  
i don't know what i skip that error are coming.
please give me some instruction that i'll follow

Comment: Did you install product-community-edition:2.3.2?

Comment: yes i use composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.3.2

Comment: So now you should have different error

Comment: Actually i  "run composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.3.2  --no-update" and later "composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition --no-update" after that "composer update" then i face that errors.

Comment: what version of magento/product-community-edition and magento/magento-cloud-metapackage and magento/product-enterprise-edition do you have when You run composer show